# Отслеживание позиции ScrollBar1->Position при изменении его размеров с помощью TrackBar

Tags: c++builder, scrollbar

**Проблема**

Моя основная программа предназначена для построения графиков. Изменение правого края относительно размеров *ScrollBar->PageSize* работает прекрасно, но возникла следующая ситуация: когда скролл бар не занимает всё своё поле и при этом упёрся в правый край, то при изменении его размеров (*ScrollBar->PageSize = TrackBar1->Position*) начинает двигаться левый край ползунка к левому краю своего пространства (что логично). Но!

Поскольку *ScrollBar->Position* берётся от левого края самого ползунка, то при изменении размеров программа не регистрирует изменения положения. Изменение положения зарегистрируется только после клика по самому скроллу.

**Что нужно**

Просто нужно чтобы отслеживалась позиция *ScrollBar->Position* при изменении его размера трекбаром.

```
void __fastcall TForm20::ScrollBar1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
                Label2->Caption = IntToStr(ScrollBar1->Position);
                ScrollBar1->Invalidate(); //Update, Invalidate - не помогает
}

void __fastcall TForm20::TrackBar1Tracking(TObject *Sender)
{
                ScrollBar1->PageSize = TrackBar1->Position;
                Label2->Caption = IntToStr(ScrollBar1->Position);
                ScrollBar1->Invalidate();
}
```

**Скрины с пошаговым разбором:**[image: Положение после запуска программы]

[image: Меняю размер с помощью трекбара, сдвигаю скролл вправо. Изменение позиции засчиталось]

[image: Убеждаемся что всё изменилось]
[image: Снова изменяю скролл. Двигаю трекбар в конец, что должно увеличить скролл бар. Изменилась левая часть, но положение (ScrollBar->Position) осталось что до изменения]
[image: И только после клика по скроллу засчиталось изменение положения]